# Can WP8 background tasks be passed an arg?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-process

I need a value from the foreground app to be used in a query I use in the background task. This value is stored in roamingSettings and gets into roamingSettings by prompting the user for it once.

Can I pass that value somehow from the foreground app to the periodic background task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read app settings from a background task, so just store your argument however you want (ApplicationSettings, IsolatedStorage file, whatever) and read it from the background task.

Comment: So you're saying that the background task can access roaming settings from the foreground app? Don't they live in different spaces/separate from each other? The video I watched with Andy Wiggly and Rob "Breakfast with" Tiffany indicated you needed to share data between the foreground app and the background task by writing to a file - but doesn't each project have its own folder, unavailable to the other?

Comment: What do you mean by "roaming settings"? Windows 8 have that, but windows phone doesn't. And no they live in the same space/folder and share isolated storage and application settings.

Comment: Yeah, I found that out; using IsolatedStorage now.

Comment: I tried _ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings_ inside the Run method of a IBackgoundTask. The settings were always null. Seems that the IBackgroundTask does not have the right to read them.